# How to escape special characters in JasperReports?

Tags: jasper-reports, special-characters, escaping

How to escape special characters in `JasperReports`?

I want to escape special characters like :- é, â, è, ^, @ in jasper reports, so is there any way we can escape this characters ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

- instead of 'é' use '\u00E9'
- instead of 'â' use '\u00E2'
- instead of 'è' use '\u00E8'

etc.

Comment: I have string comming from oracle, at a short i want to replace all the special character is it possible ? is there any api for it ?

Comment: then check what's the encoding of your db, then check what's the encoding of your jasperreports templates. bear in mind that oracle jdbc has problems transforming some special ms word characters into unicode

Answer (score 2):

If you want to escape special XML characters like `<, >` you can use CDATA:

```
<staticText>
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="14"/>
    <textElement/>
        <text><![CDATA[This is a test:<                 ]]></text>
</staticText>
```

Special characters like `é, â, è` should work great if you specify the character encoding at the beginning of the jrxml file and encode the file correctly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

If the exported report shows invalid characters you should check the jasper export. For instance for pdf export can find info [here](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=102&forumid=103&topicid=60758).

Answer (score 1):

Saving jrxml file in UTF-8 encoding does not solve problem, because .jrxml file is compiled into .jasper file and it looses information about used encoding.
Final report is then missing special characters.

Problem is solved when using /u00XX escape characters inside CDATA XML tag.
In this case the special characters are present in output PDF file.
Outside CDATA tag are escape characters not interpreted correctly.